# Mysql not giving Syntax error when it should

Tags: mysql, sql, backticks

I am trying with following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM users` 
  WHERE email = 'xyz@xyz.com'
```

This is not giving me syntax error (notice not include ` character at the starting of table name). And always gives me count as 1, although record in not there in db.

I will get the error if i remove `COUNT` from the query.

Hope this is not a bug in mysql.

Comment: what are you trying to query for? this query just counts the number of users with a specific email.

Comment: It seems to behave like the backtick is commenting out the rest of the line...

Comment: What are you using to send the query to the DB?

Comment: @Brendan Bullen you are right the query after backtick is not executing would have accepted if it was an answer

Comment: I wonder if the backtick is causing "  WHERE email = 'xyz@xyz.com' " to be treated as an alias to the table users.

Comment: interesting enough, if you put the backtick in front of users, it thinks everything after it is the table name (and says unknown table users where email =...

Comment: @Jaydee that is not the case see answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backtick seems to be commenting out the rest of the line.

I can't say why but I have tested it (through phpMyAdmin) and that it the case.